# User Account Lifecycle - ServiceNow

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, servicenow

I'm thinking about creating an automation using ServiceNow to create and edit user accounts in Azure Active Directory and On prem Active Directory. My idea is to create a form that takes the user's information and then creates the account based on the information.

I need your opinions on what can be done and what can not be done. Does ServiceNow support it? Can you use the SSO link between ServiceNow and Microsoft Azure to create an account?

Do I need to create a script that reads data from ServiceNow and passes it to Azure or On-prem Active Directory?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you will need to setup your own outbound REST calls to talk to the Microsoft Graph API.  Then a good script include and some business rules and/or workflows to execute those REST calls..  should be cake.  The only downside is that if you dont want to require a user to physically log into azure then you'll have to create the app registration in Azure AD as an application as opposed to a user... and that means that when you grant permissions to it... it gets them for the entire directory.. not just on a limited set of resources...   just a "quirk" of the current state of the MS Graph API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api